# What are the most general conditions under which the inverse image of sheaves of abelian groups has a left adjoint?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

If $f: E \to X$ is an étale map (a local homeomorphism), then the inverse image of sheaves of abelian groups $f^{-1}$ has a left adjoint, [as shown by Roland in his answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221956/left-adjoint-to-inverse-image-of-sheaves). This subsumes as a special case the construction of the *exension by zero* functor $j_!$ for $j: U \hookrightarrow X$ an open embedding.

I am curious what are the most general conditions under which we can guarantee the existence of a left adjoint? After generalizing from open embeddings to etale maps, the next step would be to check if it holds for open maps.

> **Question 1:** If $f:Y \to X$ is an open map, does $f^{-1}$ have a left adjoint? What additional hypotheses on $f$ (hopefully weaker than being a local homeomorphism) or the spaces involved would make this true?

At least for the case of the terminal map $t: X \to 1$ from a locally connected space $X$, this is true (as pointed out by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე in the comments, the locally connected assumption is necessary). The inverse image $t^{-1}$ constructs constant sheaves on $X$ out of abelian groups, and since $t^{-1}$ is exact, we can apply the adjoint functor theorem if we can merely verify that it preserves infinite products, which it obviously does.

I am not sure if this left adjoint agrees with the pushforward with proper supports $t_!$ in the case where $X$ is locally compact, but I would hope it does.

More generally, I would like to know:

> **Question 2:** What are the mildest hypotheses we can place on the map $f: Y \to X$ or the spaces involved to guarantee the existence of a left adjoint to $f^{-1}$?

Comment: The keyword must be [essential geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism). For a negative answer to Q1, consider $t^{-1}(2^I)\to t^{-1}(2)^I$. On sections, this sends a partition $(P_S)_{S\subseteq I}$ into $2^I$ clopens to the family $(C_i:=\bigcup_{i\in S}P_S)_{i\in I}$ of clopens. So if $t^{-1}$ preserves products, any family of clopens $(C_i)$ of an open set may be refined to a partition of that open set. There are (non-locally-connected) spaces where this is not possible.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right; that's probably the right keyword. I don't know much about topos theory, but I assume that for an essential geometric morphism of sheaf topoi the left adjoint $f_!$ somehow needs to be modified to give the correct left adjoint for sheaves of abelian groups, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a subtle point there. Basically, you sort of replace coproducts with direct sums. Also, it might be that $f_!$ exists on abelian groups for some non-essential gm's, I don't know.

Comment: Also note that in the "relative" case, there exist essential $f:X\to Y$ for both $X$ and $Y$ not locally connected (there is also the notion of [locally connected geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+connected+geometric+morphism), saying that the "space over $Y$" determined by $f$ is locally connected; this is strictly stronger than essential when $Y$ is not a single point, but still may happen when neither $X$ nor $Y$ is locally connected itself: e. g. every étale map is such)

Comment: A formal way to modify the left adjoint for sheaves of sets into a left adjoint for sheaves of abelian groups is to use the https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+lifting+theorem .

Comment: @MikeShulman Thanks! That looks exactly like the sort of result I wanted. Just out of curiosity, to get the dual statement for lifting of right adjoints, I assume we would just replace "left" by "right", "monadic" by "comonadic", and "coequalizers" by "equalizers"?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Yes.  Or, equivalently, apply the theorem as stated to the opposites of your given categories.